# Unable to get jQuery TOOLS Tabs to work in Liferay 5.2.3

Tags: liferay, jquery-tools

I'm using Liferay 5.2.3 and I'd like to leverage jQuery TOOLS Tabs and not the default jQuery UI tabs that ship with this version of Liferay. It doesnt seem to work. Firstly, the dock no longer drops down and the tabs don't appear.

Are there any steps I can take in order to be able to use jQuery TOOLS and the jQuery TOOLS Tabs?

Some of the articles here talk about downloading jQuery TOOLS without tabs, but obviously, I would like tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I just needed to make sure the Liferay head include which obviously includes the Liferay version of jQuery (1.2) was underneath the new version!

```
#js("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js")
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[  */
var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
/* ]]>  */
</script>
$theme.include($top_head_include)
</head>
```